# Difference in meaning: "diplomacy" and "foreign affairs"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

In a general context, is there any difference in meaning or tone between "diplomacy" and "foreign affairs"? Consider the following case.

(at a speech) I will talk about effects the TPP (Trans Pacific Partnership agreement) may have on Japanese diplomacy (or foreign affairs).

Answer (score 4):

***Foreign affairs*** and ***foreign policy*** are terms which describe a country's overall relations with foreign places; the policies in place, incidents that take place, treaties, alliances, trade agreements, military and security co-operation, as well as hostile relationships - even war.

***Diplomacy*** involves the day to day contacts and relations between countries involving ambassadors, government officials, conversations between foreign ministers and others in the relevant governments etc.